# Converting Non-Raid to Raid

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid1

I have a server that currently has one 1TB drive in it. I just bought a 1TB drive to put in Raid-1 with it. The server already has data on it, so my question is what do I have to do to make it a raid array? Do I have to clone the hard drive before I raid it? I should point out that this is the boot medium and the motherboard had a Raid controller built into it (its a Dell SC1425).

Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: Typically, converting from non-RAID to RAID or vice versa is destructive.

Comment: Make sure your backups are good before you try converting anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting a live boot/root disk to RAID is a lot of magic and usually it is not worth the effort.

You are better off with moving to the new disk first. Start it up as a degraded raid-1, copy the contents (not clone).

Then work on booting the system from it. Depending on the OS used that can be a lot of fun too.

After you are able to boot from the new disk, you just swipe the old one, adjust the partitions if necessary and add it up to the RAID.

Comment: You know what? I think you're right: it's not worth the effort. Guess I have a 2TB server instead of a 1TB server which is still fantastic. Answer accepted.